# How to integrate this exponential/logarithmic integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to solve $$\int_0^\infty\ln(x)\cdot \exp(x)\cdot x^{-x}\;\mathrm{d}x,$$
but I do not know how. Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $x^{-x} = e^{-x \ln(x)}$.  Try a change of variables $u = x - x \ln(x)$.

Comment: It is not allowed to change our original variable to any other name in a definite integral?

Comment: Who's not allowing it?

Comment: I am asking if I have an definite integral like above; can I change my variable to any other name? I don't mean about your solution Prof. I ask generally.  :)

Comment: In general, change of variable in a definite integral goes like this: $$\int_a^b f(g(t))\ g'(t)\ dt = \int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(u)\ du$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\ln(x) \exp(x) x^{-x} = \ln(x) \exp(x) e^{-x \ln(x)} = \ln(x) \exp(x(1-\ln(x)))$$ and set $x - x \ln(x) = t$ and simplify to get a nice answer!

Answer (score 2):

HINT: First, $x^{-x}=e^{-x\ln x}$. Now combine the exponentials, and ask yourself what the derivative of $x-x\ln x$ is.

Comment: $4$ answers in $46$ seconds!